# SonarQube always displays 0.0% code coverage for Javascript project

Tags: javascript, code-coverage, sonarqube

I am new to SonarQube, and am trying to use it with a Javascript project, on Windows.  I've followed the doc as best I can and am successfully seeing the static code analysis sonar does.

I am using JsTestDriver for my unit tests, and producing a code coverage report file.  I see the test results in SonarQube, but the code coverage is always reported as 0.0%.  If I don't specify a code coverage report file, or specify a file name that doesn't exist, the code coverage block in my dashboard does not display at all, so I know Sonar is seeing the file in some sense.  I have run jGenHtml against the file and it produces correct HTML output, with the results I expect, so I know the file has content and is formatted correctly.

I have specified the location for these files in my Javascript plugin settings.  As indicated by the doc and some forum posts I found, I used the relative directory path test/results for the actual unit test results (which show up fine) and the relative file name test/results/code-coverage.dat for the coverage report. I've also tried specifying the file as an absolute path, but it didn't help.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of the JavaScript plugin are you running?
Do you confirm that the following project sample work fine on your side: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/javascript/javascript-sonar-runner-JsTestDriver? Can you spot any differences between your coverage file and the one generated by the project sample?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have version 1.4 of the plugin.  I haven't run all this with the sample project yet.  Let me do that and I'll post again with a comparison.

Comment: David's suggestion of comparing my output file with the one created from the sample app led to a solution.  Thanks!  See the answer I posted for details

Answer (score 0):

This is working now, thanks to the suggestion comment from David RACODON.

It seems my code coverage report contains file paths that look like this:

SF:H:\perforce_workspaces\atlasjs_main\.\test\lib\jquery-1.8.2.js

I edited the file to remove the \.\ bit in the middle, and now Sonar is able to import the file.

The sample project's coverage report does not have this in its paths, and I note that I have been using a slightly newer verson of jsTestDriver than the sample app.  I am using 1.3.5, while the sample app comes with 1.3.4.b.  I don't know if they changed the output format between revisions of the coverage plugin, or if this is something specific with my project.  In any event, I should be able to figure out a way to prevent or remove the offending characters.

Note that jgenhtml was able to read my file just fine with the extraneoud \.\ so this seems to be an issue with Sonar being very picky.